# Drupal menu activation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-navigation

I have a probably common question. For example whe have material type "news" and page made by views that displaying news teasers. We have menu item "news", that link to our view page and have url example.com/news. Each news page have url like example.com/news/[news title]. How could we set menu item "News" to be active on such pages /news/[news title]?

Comment: I know about menu_set_active_item and of course we could do it in module, but maybe thare is better way?

Answer (score 1):

The [Menu Trail By Path](http://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) module does exactly that:

> This module sets the active-trail on menu items according to the current url.

I've used it for ages and it works great

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module. It allows you to set the active trail based on url, view, content type, etc. Very powerful interface.